# Konjunktiv 1, 2?

Tags: grammaticality

Ich habe eine Frage zum Konjunktiv. Wann genau soll ich ihn nutzen, auch bezüglich des Stils?

Bsp.:

> Beim klassischen neuronalen Netzwerk liegt ein Datensatz gelabelter Elemente vor. Jedes Element hat ein Label, das es einer bestimmten Klasse zuordnet. Im einfachsten Fall können alle Elemente in zwei Klassen unterteilt werden. Das trainierte Netzwerk ordnet ungelabelte Eingangsdaten einer Klasse zu.

Jetzt möchte ich über einen möglichen, konkreten Einsatz sprechen. Frage mich aber, ob ich dann den Konjunktiv nutzen sollte.

> In einem konkreten Fall entschiede das Netzwerk, ob ein Bild eine
> Katze oder einen Hund darstellen würde. Ein solcher Ansatz wäre ein Fall des überwachten Lernens bzw. „supervised Learning“.

Ich habe mich für Konjunktiv 2 entschieden, da der beschriebene Fall innerhalb meiner Auswertung auf keinen Fall durchgeführt wird, aber prinzipiell möglich ist. Passt das so?

Comment: Ein neuronales Netz ist kein Eigenname, daher schreibt man das Adjektiv natürlich klein. Ebenso das überwachte Lernen.

Comment: Dass der beschriebene Fall auf keinen Fall durchgeführt wird, wird im Text nicht richtig deutlich. Dadurch wirkt der Konjunktiv II seltsam.

Comment: @RHa Ja das ist klar, ist ja auch nur ein Ausschnitt, deswegen habe ich das noch mal explizit hingeschrieben.

Comment: Ich finde, der Konjunktiv 2 passt trotzdem nicht gut. Es ist nicht abwegig, dass eine KI das beschriebene tut. Es ist  eine Annahme für das hier betrachtete Beispiel, weshalb Konjunktiv 1 imho richtig ist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In einem konkreten Fall entschiede das Netzwerk, ob
> ein Bild eine Katze oder einen Hund darstellen würde.
> Ein solcher Ansatz wäre ein Fall des überwachten
> Lernens bzw. „supervised Learning“.

Zunächst zur Groß- und Kleinschreibung, die von einigen anderen Antwortern angesprochen wurde:

"*supervised Learning*" sollte tatsächlich "supervised learning" geschrieben werden, weil, wie @HubertSchölnast ausgeführt hat, innerhalb der Anführungszeichen die englische Grammatik gilt, die die Kleinschreibung verlangt.

Ganz anders liegt der Fall beim "*Überwachten Lernen*", das tatsächlich ein Fachbegriff aus der KI-Forschung ist. (Die erste mir bekannte Erwähnung findet sich bei T. Kohonen, Self-Organizing Maps.) Das sollte, wie jeder andere Fachbegriff, großgeschrieben werden, eben weil es ein *Bestandteil einer festen Fügung* ist. "Überwachtes Lernen" ist ja nicht generell das Erlernen von irgendwas mit eben einer Überwachung dabei (analog zu etwa "betreutem Wohnen"), sondern ein ganz bestimmtes, definiertes  Verfahren zum Training eines neuronalen Netzes. Ich gebe allerdings zu, daß KI-Forschung ein eher obskures Fachgebiet ist und die Bezeichnung nicht notwendigerweise allgemein als Fachbegriff verstanden werden wird. Es mag deshalb - in Abhängigkeit vom Auditorium, an das sich der Satz richtet - geraten erscheinen, den Begriff zur Verdeutlichung in Anführungszeichen zu setzen, in einer Fußnote zu verdeutlichen oder Ähnliches.

Die Anwendung des Konjunktivs ist in dem gegebenen Satz zumindest teilweise korrekt:

> In einem konkreten Fall entschiede das Netzwerk, ob [...]

Korrekt. Hier wird die *Möglichkeit*, daß das (nämlich das Entscheiden des Netzwerks) geschieht, ins Auge gefaßt und dieser (hypothetische) Fall behandelt.

> ob ein Bild eine Katze oder einen Hund darstellen würde.

Falsch. In dem Moment, in dem das Netzwerk diese Frage entscheidet, liegt bereits eine Darstellung vor - und zwar nicht hypothetisch, sondern wirklich. (Ansonsten hätte das Netzwerk - auch hypothetisch - nichts zu entscheiden.) Hier ist also nicht eine Möglichkeit ins Auge gefaßt, sondern es wird eine real vorliegende Darstellung beurteilt! Deshalb:

> In einem konkreten Fall entschiede das Netzwerk, ob
> ein Bild eine Katze oder einen Hund **darstellt**.

*Wenn* das Bild nun einen Hund *darstellte* (wir nehmen das mal als Möglichkeit an, deshalb Konjunktiv), dann ... könnte alles Mögliche passieren, aber das Netzwerk entscheidet zunächst darüber, ob ein Hund (oder eine Katze) dargestellt *wird* (tatsächlich, deshalb Indikativ).

Comment: Danke für deinen Beitrag. Der Begriff Supervised Learning wird im Deutschen, soweit ich das mitbekommen habe, parallel zum Begriff des Überwachten Lernens auch als Fachbegriff benutzt. Deswegen habe ich mich für die Großschreibung entschieden. siehe z.B. hier: https://datasolut.com/wiki/supervised-learning/
https://www.computerweekly.com/de/definition/Ueberwachtes-Lernen-Supervised-Learning

Comment: Beim vorletzten Abschnitt kommt es aber, meiner Meinung nach, auf den Blickwinkel an. Wenn ich es aus der Sicht des hypothetischen Netzwerkes betrachte, dann würde ich dir zustimmen. Wenn ich es jedoch von "außerhalb" betrachte, ist das Bild ebenso hypothetisch wie das Netzwerk.
Wobei ich durchaus glaube, dass dine Variante besser klingt.

Comment: @SkoboDo: auch von "außerhalb betrachtet" gilt: die Möglichkeit, daß das Netzwerk entscheidet, mag hypothetisch sein, aber *wenn der hypothetische Fall eintritt*, *wenn* es also entscheidet, *dann* liegt tatsächlich(!) etwas vor, worüber es entscheidet - eben eine Abbildung einer Katze oder eines Hundes.

Comment: @SkoboDo: Man kann "supervised learning" durchaus groß schreiben, aber dann muß man alles groß schreiben ("Supervised Learning", nicht "supervised Learning") und dann sollte es auch ohne Anführungszeichen geschrieben werden. Also entweder z.B.: "Ich rede über Supervised Learning." oder "Ich rede über 'supervised learning'.".

Answer (score 1):

Nicht verkehrt, aber der Konjunktiv II passt meines Erachten nicht zu Deiner Intention, ein mögliches aber nicht durchgeführtes Szenario für den Einsatz der KI, aber denoch kein abwegiges als Gedankenexperiment zu behandeln.

Hier Dein Orginal:

> Jetzt möchte ich über einen möglichen, konkreten Einsatz sprechen. Frage mich aber, ob ich dann den Konjunktiv nutzen sollte:

> > In einem konkreten Fall entschiede das Netzwerk, ob ein Bild eine Katze oder einen Hund darstellen würde. Ein solcher Ansatz wäre ein Fall des überwachten Lernens bzw. „supervised Learning“.

**Im Fall möglicher und realistischer Annahmen nimmt man** statt des hier verwendeten Konjunktiv II üblicherweise **den Konjunktiv I**; den Konjunktiv I zu verwenden ist insbesondere sehr beliebt bei Gedankenexperimenten. Das kann man dann gerne auch noch mit einem "Angenommen" einleiten, um den Lesern klar zu machen, dass es sich um hypothetisches Szenario handelt:

> Angenommen, das Netzwerk entscheide darüber, ob ein Bild eine Katze oder einen Hund zeige. (...).

Schriftlich ist das gutes Deutsch. Im Gesprochenen findet man es inzwischen seltener und es klingt heutzutage schon etwas gehoben. Bleibt man bei der Möglichkeitsform, würde man häufig mit dem Hilfsverb 'werden' (in der Form 'würde') formulieren - auch wenn es sprachlich die gleiche Skepsis dem Szenario gegenüber ausdrückt wie Dein Orignal):

> Nehmen wir an, das Netzwerk würde darüber entscheiden, ob das Bild eine Katze oder einen Hund zeigt. (...)

Man könnte den gleichen Satz auch im Indikativ formulieren ohne dass sich an der Bedeutung etwas ändert, solange er mit "Angenommen" eingeleitet wird. Die Formulierungen im Konjunktiv oder mit 'würde' wie oben machen aber deutlicher, dass wir ein hypothetisches Szenario betrachten - und man kann sicher mit Recht argumentieren, dass der Indikativ hier nicht her gehört:

> Angenommen, das Netzwerk entscheidet darüber, ob ein Bild eine Katze oder einen Hund zeigt. (...)

Den **Konjunktiv II wählt man** eher, **wenn wir ein unmögliches**, wenig wünschenswertes oder sehr wenig wahrscheinliches, unrealistisches **Szenario betrachten**:

> Angenommen, dass Netzwerk entschiede letztendlich darüber, ob ein Studiengang geschlossen oder weitergeführt würde... (...)

Ein solches Szenario mag man sich dann als Schreiber nicht vorstellen.

Etwas allgemeiner zusammengefasst:

Konjunktiv I verwendet man für das Kennzeichnen von indirekter Rede oder auch von Annahmen (wie hier im Ausgansszenario), Wünschen oder Aufforderungen.

Konjunktiv II verwendet man, wenn man irreale Wünsche oder Aussagen kennzeichnen möchte - oder Konjunktiv I nicht eindeutig als dieser erkennbar ist. Die Umschreibung mit 'würde' kann man alternativ zu diesem wählen und sollte sie wählen, wenn der Konjunktiv II nicht von der Präteritums-Form zu unterscheiden ist. Siehe bspw. auch [hier](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/konjunktiv-1-oder-2) auf den Seiten des Duden.

Comment: Danke für deinen Beitrag.

Answer (score -3):

Richtig wäre:

> In einem konkreten Fall **entscheidet** das Netzwerk, ob **es** ein Bild **einer** Katze oder **eines Hundes** darstellen **soll.** Ein solcher Ansatz **ist** ein Fall des **überwachten** Lernens bzw. „**supervised learning**“.

1. Falsch: *»entschiede«;* richtig: *»entscheidet«*
   In dem beschriebenen Fall trifft das Netzwerk tatsächlich diese Entscheidung. Es handelt sich also nicht um eine Möglichkeit, sondern um eine Tatsache. Daher ist hier der Konjunktiv falsch und es ist stattdessen der Indikativ zu verwenden.
   Aber selbst, wenn ein Konjunktiv angebracht wäre, würden deutsche Muttersprachler nicht die Form *»entschiede«* verwenden. Diese Form ist veraltet. Deutsche Muttersprachler würden schreiben: *»In einem konkreten Fall würde das Netzwerk entscheiden, ob ...«*
2. Der Inhalt des untergeordneten Nebensatzes (der Teil, der mit dem Wort *»ob«* beginnt) ist ein indirekter Fragesatz. Die direkte Version dieser Frage sieht so aus:

   > **Soll** es ein Bild einer Katze oder eines Hundes darstellen?

   Die in der Frage verwendete Version verwendet anstelle einer Form des Modalverbs *»sollen«* das Verb *»würde«*, das gemeinsam mit dem Infinitiv *»darstellen«* die Ersatzkonstruktion des Konjunktiv II ergibt. Auch das ist eine korrekte Konstruktion, allerdings unterscheiden sich die beiden Sätze ein wenig in ihrer Bedeutung:

   - **soll:** Wenn man dieses Wort wählt, betrachtet man den Vorgang vom Standpunkt der Gegenwart aus und stellt die Entscheidung als einen Vorgang dar, der unausweichlich in der Zukunft geschehen wird. Nach spricht hier also von Fakten.
   - **würde:** Hier spricht man nicht von Fakten, sondern von Möglichkeiten, die in der Zukunft realisiert sein könnten.

   Beide Varianten können hier verwendet werden. Ich persönlich finde es aber besser, von Tatsachen als von Möglichkeiten zu sprechen, daher gebe ich der Version mit dem Wort *»soll«* den Vorzug. - Aber ich gebe zu, dass das eine Entscheidung des persönlichen Geschmacks ist.
3. Fehlendes Subjekt *»es«* im untergeordneten Nebensatz.
   In dem untergeordneten Nebensatz, der mit der Subjunktion *»ob«* beginnt, muss direkt nach diesem Wort ein Subjekt vorhanden sein. Das war hier nicht der Fall. Aus dem Kontext lässt sich schließen, dass nur *»das Netzwerk«* gemeint sein kann. Diese Nominalgruppe steht aber bereits im übergeordneten Hauptsatz (sie ist auch dort das Subjekt), daher kann stattdessen als Referenz auf diese Nominalgruppe das Personalpronomen *»es«* verwendet werden.
4. Falscher Fall von *»einer Katze«* und *»eines Hundes«*
   Dem Wort *»Bild«* ist als Attribut eine Aufzählung nachgestellt, die angibt, was das Bild darstellt. Dieses Attribut wurde im Akkusativ angegeben, es muss aber im Genitiv stehen (Genitivattribut). Daher müssen alle Elemente der Aufzählung im Genitiv stehen.
5. Indikativ *»ist«* im zweiten Satz.
   Das vorgeschlagene Wort *»wäre«* ist der Konjunktiv II des Verbs *»sein«*. Immer wenn ein Konjunktiv II verwendet wird, muss die Frage *»unter welcher Voraussetzung?«* gestattet sein:

   > Korrekte Verwendung des (Ersatz-)Konjunktivs im ersten Satz:
   > A: »Ich würde morgen für dich einkaufen gehen.«
   > B: »Was muss geschehen, damit du das wirklich tust?«
   > A: »Du müsstest mir nur sagen, was ich kaufen soll.«

   > Falsche Verwendung des (Ersatz-)Konjunktivs im ersten Satz:
   > A: »Ich würde morgen für dich einkaufen gehen.«
   > B: »Was muss geschehen, damit du das wirklich tust?«
   > A: »Äh - gar nichts. Ich gehe morgen auf jeden Fall für dich einkaufen.«

   Wenn die Frage nach einer Voraussetzung erkennen lässt, dass gar keine Voraussetzung erfüllt werden muss, dann war der Konjunktiv die falsche Wahl. Es ist dann besser, der Indikativ zu verwenden. In vorliegenden Fall muss keine noch unerfüllte Bedingung erfüllt werden, um diesen Ansatz mit überwachtem Lernen gleichsetzen zu können. Es ist eine Tatsache, dass dieser Ansatz überwachtes Lernen ist.
   Eine Ausnahme von dieser Bedingungs-Regel ist der Einsatz des Konjunktivs als Höflichkeitsform, den man aber nur in Fragen verwendet um einen unhöflichen Imperativ zu vermeiden:

> Konjunktiv der Höflichkeit: »Würden Sie mir bitte eine Tasse Kaffee bringen?«
> Ohne Konjunktiv = unhöflicher Imperativ: »Bringen Sie mir bitte eine Tasse Kaffee!«
> (Noch unhöflicher wird es nur, wenn man das Wort *»bitte«* weglässt.)

6. Falsche Großschreibung des Adjektivs *»überwachten«*
   Großzuschreiben sind in deutschen Sätze nur die jeweils ersten Wörter des Satzes sowie alle Substantive (zu denen auch substantivierte Verben, substantivierte Adjektive usw. zu zählen sind). Adjektive, die nicht substantiviert sind, und nicht das erste Wort eines Satzes sind, sind kleinzuschreiben.
   Davon ausgenommen sind nur Adjektive, die Bestandteile fester Fügungen sind, die als Eigennamen verwendet werden (z.B. *»der Deutsche Bundestag«* = Eigenname, aber *»die deutsche Sprache«* = kein Eigenname.) Die Wortgruppe *»überwachtes Lernen«* (bzw. im Genitiv: *»des überwachten Lernens«*) ist kein Eigenname, daher ist *»überwachten«* auch nicht großzuschreiben.
7. Falsche Großschreibung des zitierten Begriffs *»„supervised learning“«*
   Nachdem diese Wortgruppe als ein aus dem Englischen zitierter Begriff in Anführungszeichen steht, gilt innerhalb der Anführungszeichen die englische Grammatik. Dort werden auch Substantive kleingeschrieben, sonst gelten aber dieselben Regeln, die schon im Punkt 6 behandelt wurden, einschließlich der Ausnahme für Eigennamen. Aber *»supervised learning«* ist weder im Deutschen noch im Englischen ein Eigenname, daher sind beide Wörter dieses Begriffs kleinzuschreiben.

Comment: Das Netzwerk kann nicht darüber entscheiden, ob etwas Bestimmtes dargestellt werden **soll**, weil das nur derjenige weiß, der das Bild gezeichnet hat. Mag sein, daß er schlecht zeichnet und das Bild was anderes darstellt, als es **darstellen soll**, aber das wird kein Netzwerk beurteilen können, solange es nicht Gedanken lesen kann.